# Modificar valor dentro de un record search

Tags: odoo

Tengo un **record** como resultado de una búsqueda en `odoo` 12 y necesito saber como puedo modificar algún valor contenido dentro de este **record** y salvarlo, aquí os dejo mi código:

```
@api.multi
    def write(self, vals):
        v = self.env['utm.campaign'].search([('default_campaign', '=', True)])
        if v.id:
            v.default_campaign = False
            res = super(wc_fill_fields_crm_lead_campaign, self).write(v)
        return res
```

Answer (score 0):

puedes modificar los valores con los que vas a actualizar el record antes de invocar al método "super", que es el como tal hace la persistencia en base de datos. Estos valores se encuentran dentro de la variable "vals", que no es más que un arreglo asociativo.

Entonces el código te puede quedar como sigue:

```
vals['default_campaign'] = v.id   *#= False o el valor que sea que quieras darle*

res = super(wc_fill_fields_crm_lead_campaign, self).write(vals)

return res
```